# django: Celery how to get a list of task results by their ids

Tags: python, django, celery

Wanted to check if there is a way to optimize the process of celery task results checking.

For example, I have the following code:

```
for task_id in tasks: # tasks is a list of celery task ids
    res = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
    if res.successful():
        tasks_ids[task_id] = res.result # here I am storing task results
```

The problem with current approach is that I have to loop over celery tasks and check them one by one. And as well as I am using a database results backend it will produce a query per each celery taskid (at least I think so).

So I wanted to check if there is a way to retrieve all results at once? Is there. Is there app.AsyncResult() analogue which operates with a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery has a [ResultSet](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html#ResultSet) class to work with this, it has "join()" and "native_join()" methods to do that.
There is a drawback as the doc says, the database backends does not implement the "native_join()" (these backends do implement it: amqp, Redis and cache), because of that the ResultSet could be a really expensive, similar to your current approach. By the way, I think you could take a look to the doc and API and see if you find something which could help you.
I do not know how hard could be add that support to database backend (you would need to implement "get_many()" as [the API says](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.backends.base.html) says. However, you could evaluate changing the backend.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: It looks like the ResultSet accepts a list of result objects. I wonder if doing something like ResultSet([app.AsyncResult(task_id) for task_id in task_ids]) would be expensive operation as well

Comment: @Oleg-tarasenko, Yes it does accept a list of results. AsyncResult is "lazy" until you call some method explicitly. technically until AsyncResult._get_task_meta() is executed, "_get_task_meta()" calls "AsyncResult.backend.get_task_meta()" at that point it could be a  expensive operation, because it does the heavy operation.